# Not facing any GUI freezing issue though we updates GUI components from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

As part of learning SwingWorker on Java swing I created a simple program where a different thread(Other than EDT) is doing some background task and once thats done that thread is updating GUI component (JTextArea).

As I understand if we try to update GUI components from an outside thread ,other than EDT , then UI might get freezed. But this is not happening. I really would like to create that situation(Freeze UI) so as to understand it better. Below is my code that I tried. Can some one help me saying what I need to do on my code so that UI is getting freezed.

## App.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        }); 

    }

}
```

## MainFrame.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JButton btn,btn2;
    private JTextArea txtArea;

    public MainFrame() {
        super("Hello World");

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        btn = new JButton("Click Me!");
        btn2 = new JButton("Click Me New!");
        txtArea = new JTextArea();
        btn.addActionListener(this);


        add(txtArea,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(btn,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(btn2,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setSize(600,800);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        MyTestThread extThr = new MyTestThread();
        extThr.setBtnRef(txtArea);
        extThr.start();
    }

}
```

## MyTestThread.java

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MyTestThread extends Thread {

    private int i = 0;
    private JTextArea txtAreaRef;

    public void setBtnRef(JTextArea ta) {
        this.txtAreaRef = ta;
    }

    public void run() {

        while (i < 500000) {

            try {
                txtAreaRef.append("test"+i+"\n");
                i=i+1;
                sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: *"As I understand if we try to update GUI components from an outside thread ,other than EDT , then UI might get freezed."* - No, if you update the UI outside of the EDT you may end up with dirty paints and other threaded issues (like race conditions).  If you want to try and see a "UI freeze", remove the thread

Comment: @MadProgrammer , So , SwingWorker class is applicable in case of long running task to run in background and to communicate between threads - EDT and NON-EDT?

Comment: `SwingWorker#doInBackground` will execute off the EDT, it's `process` method will execute in the EDT

Comment: GUI freeze can be caused by long process (such as sleep) **on the EDT**, not off it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have no idea where you got that information from, but calling GUI updates outside of the EDT do not cause UI freezing.

If you want to produce a freeze, try making an infinite loop inside the EDT, like this.

This will cause the UI to permanently freeze.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            //MyTestThread extThr = new MyTestThread();
            //extThr.setBtnRef(txtArea);
            //extThr.start();

            while(true) {}
    }
```

Comment: So , SwingWorker class is applicable in case of long running task to run in background and to communicate between threads - EDT and NON-EDT?